# Another could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Yes I know a similar question has been asked many times, but I am sorry none of answers have really helped me or I missed something important.

I want to make registration when posted data from client are in format:

```
{
    "email": "asouausdhnsabnsmsd.s@s.com",
    "first_name": "s",
    "last_name": "d",
    "password": "f"
}
```

and server return:

```
{
    "results": {
        "email": "asouausdhnsabnsmsd.s@s.com",
        "first_name": "s",
        "last_name": "d"
    }
}
```

When I post data I got:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /api/register Could not resolve URL for
>   hyperlinked relationship using view name "customuser-detail". You may
>   have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly
>   configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

So I have serializers.py like:

```
class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        try:
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            return user
        except KeyError:
            return user


class RegisterUserRetrieveSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    results = RegisterUserSerializer(source='*')
```

Then api viewsets in views.py:

```
class RegisterUserViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                          viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (parsers.JSONParser,)
    serializer_class = serializers.RegisterUserSerializer
    model = CustomUser

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.save()
            serializer = serializers.RegisterUserRetrieveSerializer(user, context={'request': request})
            results = serializer.data
            return Response(results, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router_without_trailing_slashes = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'register', RegisterUserViewSet, base_name='customuser')
router_without_trailing_slashes.register(r'register', RegisterUserViewSet, base_name='customuser')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^templates/', include('core.main.urls'), name='templates'),

    url(r'^api/', include(router_without_trailing_slashes.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

The new user is saved correctly to db so I suppose the error is somehow connected with RegisterUserRetrieveSerializer.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are including the `url` field in the serializer, but DRF is unable to generate that url, because there is no detail view for the serializer.

There are two options:

1. Remove the `url` field from the serializer
2. Add mixins.RetrieveModelMixin to the ViewSet, so that the serializer can generate a detail url for the instance

Answer (score 0):

Error is happening due to the 'url' field included in fields list in serializer.

After adding 'url' field you need to define the view_name and lookup_field for that url in extra_kwargs.

```py
class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        extra_kwargs = {
               "url":{
                  "view_name": "customuser-detail",
                  "lookup_field": "pk"
               }
```